# Can PHP can be use for building application like Kiosk Locker?

Tags: php, kiosk, interfacing

The php program should can control the locker to open or close by entering the correct credentials in kiosk application, seems like interfacing with hardware. Is this possible in php?

Comment: You mean can PHP be used to build embedded or console/kiosk apps that interact with hardware and/or drivers? Yes (in the abstract)... But why PHP?

Comment: You could use PHP as the bridge app,but you will need something written in another language. So you could create the app in C# and then send the commands to the C# app using php.

Answer (score 0):

short answer: No.

Long answer: Doing something like this Might be possible with a custom PHP Extension, but would always be an very dirty, unwieldy solution. Php is designed to run on a webserver, generating pages. Using it to do System programming is pretty much impossible, simply by the way the language and underlying technology is designed.

You will be way better off looking at a commercial solution like SiteKiosk.

Comment: It is very possible, and is has been happening for years.  No, I wouldn't recommend it, but it isn't as far fetched as you might think.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1609167/362536 http://gtk.php.net/ http://winbinder.org/

Answer (score 0):

to be honest i think it is :-)
on the OS where php code is running on, there should be a program or command to lock/unlock the kiosk.
the only thing php does is to execute that command/application using

```
exec();
```

command.